# Run callback saved in variable on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, callback

I have an object containing a number of buttons (label and callback) which I dynamically want to add to the DOM:

```
var buttons = {
    'Save': function() {
        return false;
    },
    'Abort': function() {}
};

for(label in buttons) {
    $('#buttonbar').append('<button>' + label + '</button>');

    var callback = buttons[label];
    $('#buttonbar button:last-child').click(function() {
        //var result = callback();
        alert(callback);
    });
}
```

But regardless which button I click, the variable callback always contains the function of the last button. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YyG6J/).

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That helped me to solve it. I will edit my question.

Comment: If you feel the need to post a solution, you should put it in an answer, not the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [the hint given by Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) I found the solution:

```
var buttons = {
    'Save': function() {
        return false;
    },
    'Abort': function() {}
};

for(label in buttons) {
    $('#buttonbar').append('<button>' + label + '</button>');

    var callback = buttons[label];
    (function(cb) {
        $('#buttonbar button:last-child').click(function() {
            alert(cb);
        });
    })(callback);
}
```